# How to use optparse to have a flags argument require another argument

Tags: ruby, optparse

I have a tool that I'm updating and need to have an argument require another argument, for example:

```
require 'optparse'

OPTIONS = {}

OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.on('-t', '--type INPUT', String, 'Verify a type'){ |o| OPTIONS[:type] = o }
end.parse!

def help_page
  puts 'ruby test.rb -t dev'
end

def gather_type
  case OPTIONS[:type]
  when /dev/
    unlock(OPTIONS[:type])
  else
    help_page
  end
end

def unlock(type)
  if type == 'unlock' #Find out what type by passing argument another argument
    puts 'Unlock account'
  else
    puts 'Reset account'
  end
end

def start
  case
  when OPTIONS[:type]
    gather_type
  else
    help_page
  end
end

start
```

When this is run you get the following:

```
C:\Users\bin\ruby>ruby test.rb -t dev=unlock
Reset account
C:\Users\bin\ruby>ruby test.rb -t dev=reset
Reset account
```

Now that's all well and dandy but what I want to do is give the `dev` part an argument and go from there to decide if it's an unlock or if it's a reset:

`ruby test.rb -t dev=unlock` OR `ruby test.rb -t dev=reset`

After that I want the `unlock(type)` method to determine what argument was given to the flags argument and output the correct information, so

```
C:\Users\bin\ruby>ruby test.rb -t dev=unlock
Unlock account 

C:\Users\bin\ruby>ruby test.rb -t dev=reset
Reset account
```

How can I go about to determine if an argument was given to the argument of the flag?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that if you put an options in parenthesis you can get what I'm asking:

```
require 'optparse'

OPTIONS = {}

OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.on('-t', '--type INPUT[=INPUT]', String, 'Verify a type'){ |o| OPTIONS[:type] = o }
end.parse!

def help_page
  puts 'ruby test.rb -t dev'
end

def gather_type
  case OPTIONS[:type]
  when /dev/
    unlock(OPTIONS[:type])
  else
    help_page
  end
end

def unlock(type)
  if type =~ /unlock/ #Find out what type by passing argument another argument
    puts 'Unlock account'
  elsif type =~ /reset/
    puts 'Reset account'
  else
    puts 'No flag given defaulting to unlock'  
  end
end

def start
  case
  when OPTIONS[:type]
    gather_type
  else
    help_page
  end
end

start


C:\Users\bin\ruby>ruby test.rb -t dev
No flag given defaulting to unlock

C:\Users\bin\ruby>ruby test.rb -t dev=unlock
Unlock account

C:\Users\bin\ruby>ruby test.rb -t dev=reset
Reset account
```